# How to get the nearest match for the regular expression

Tags: python, regex

I have a code for extracting date from a text (format = mm-dd-yyyy) using regular expressions.

**Note**: The text is obtained using OCR on a bill image. So, the expected date format is mm-dd-yyyy but it can be any random text as it is obtained using OCR.

```
import re
date_reg_exp = re.compile('\d{2}[-/.]\d{2}[-/.]\d{4}') #works for mm-dd-yyyy
matches_list=date_reg_exp.findall(test_str)
for match in matches_list2:
  print match
```

If I have a string `'This is a text extracted from OCR 09-11-2015'` the above code works and results the Date as output `'09-11-2015'`. But, if I have a string `'This is o text extractud fram OCR 09-11-201 5'` or `'This is o text xtractud fram OCR 09-11-201'` or `'This is o text xtractud fram OCR O9-11-201'` it fails. How to I write a code for such scenario where it also picks up the nearest match.

Comment: It depends on the definition of "nearest". And your example can handler by removing space before match.

Comment: Okay. Let me be more specific. If I have a string `'The String is 09-11-201'` which is a nearest match for the regular expression. This should be printed as the output.
Output - `09-11-201`

Comment: Are all your month and days in correct format, just the years are messed up?

Comment: Added few more specifics in the question. Please check once again.

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways you could implement approximate matching with regular expressions. The most "theoretically straightforward" approach would most probably require you to perform an [edit-distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edit_distance)-like [dynamic programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming) computation over the regexp's [DFA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_finite_automaton).

This being a fairly tricky algorithm to code, there are not too many implementations of it lying around. The most famous is known as [Agrep](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agrep) (technically, the `agrep` tool implements several algorithms, but is most known, among other things, for the fuzzy regexp matching).

Brief googling by this keyword comes up with [this library](https://github.com/laurikari/tre/), which seems to have Python bindings and might be exactly what you need.

Comment: If you are familiar with the library please help me in understanding by providing an example.

Comment: What is wrong with the example that is already given there?
https://github.com/laurikari/tre/blob/master/python/example.py

Answer (score 0):

Try-

```
O?\d{1,2}[-/\.]\d{2}[-/\.][\d\s]{2,}
```

As below-

```
>>>import re
>>>s = """If I have a string 'This is a text extracted from OCR 09-11-2015' the above code works and results the Date as output '09-11-2015'. But, if I have a string 'This is o text extractud fram OCR 09-11-201 5' or 'This is o text xtractud fram OCR 09-11-201' or 'This is o text xtractud fram OCR O9-11-201' it fails. How to I write a code for such scenario where it also picks up the nearest match."""
>>>re.findall(r'O?\d{1,2}[-/\.]\d{2}[-/\.][\d\s]{2,}',s)
>>>['09-11-2015', '09-11-2015', '09-11-201 5', '09-11-201', 'O9-11-201']
```

Then try to replace all `O` with `0`.

```
>>>[i.replace('O','0') for i in ['09-11-2015', '09-11-2015', '09-11-201 5', '09-11-201', 'O9-11-201']]
>>>['09-11-2015', '09-11-2015', '09-11-201 5', '09-11-201', '09-11-201']
```

See live <kbd>[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/hN6aV1/5)</kbd>

OR- if there is date separator in the date e.g. `/`,`.`,`-` then below should extract dates- It considers all [l33t](http://qntm.org/l33t) characters. like `$` for `5`

```
\b[\w\$\s]{2}\s*[\.-/-]\s*[\w\$]{2,}\s*[\.-/-]\s*[\w\$]{2,}
```

See live <kbd>[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/rJ1sM9/1)</kbd>

N.B. you will not get 100% accurate result by no means since your data is a disaster, instead use good ocr engine like [Abbyy](http://www.abbyyindia.com/) that can increase the accuracy.

---

**EDIT**

If you want to implement some sort of fuzzymatch/ [Levenshtein Distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) then use [FuzzyWuzzy](https://github.com/seatgeek/fuzzywuzzy) module.

Comment: This works fine with an extra space. But In case of a digit missing like `'09-11-201` it fails. I need a generalized `regex` or some sort of algorithm that helps in picking up such scenarios.

Comment: Could you post all possible format of dates whereas as i can make regex generalized.

Comment: For now I have only one format of dates `mm-dd-yyyy`. I am actually working on OCR (extracting date from bills). So I need this scenario. Heard of Levenshtein but I was unaware of its implementation in this case as `Date` is not an English word.

Comment: Thanks mate for putting in your effort. But, again it fails for `'09-11-201S'`. We can't keep writing `regex` for every scenario right ? I think I need to go through the methodologies that @KT was mentioning.

Comment: Edited answer see  suggestion about `Levenshtein Distance `

Comment: Yes, I thought of implementing the `Levenshtein Distance` itself. But, I don't know what to compare against. (as the parameters for that function will be two strings `1.Output` `2.Original Answer`). How will we know the original answer(as we are having multiple receipts with multiple dates)

Answer (score 0):

**This is not what the title demands**
but might turn up useful for your scenario as you mentioned Levenshtein distance.

```
from dateutil.parser import parse

s = 'This is o text xtractud fram OCR O9-11-201'

parse(s, fuzzy=True)

datetime.datetime(201, 9, 11, 0, 0)
```

Dateutil offers a fuzzy datetime parser.

This works for `'09-11-201'` but won't work for `'09-11-201 5'`

Comment: Will it work for `'O9-11-2015'` or `'09-11-201S'` ? because OCR engine may get confused for `0` and `O` and also for `5` and `S`.

Comment: By mistake I had used `O` instead of `0` in the above example. It worked here because the alphabet is not in 'between' the date and is simply left off.
So, it won't work for alphabets. You can write some more code to extract date after replacing all S and O if you are not able to find any date where you are supposed to find.